# Is the windows permission system different from that of Linux?

Tags: permissions, windows-10

I have two hard disks in my pc.

1. Primary Disk : Where Ubuntu and windows are dual booted
2. Secondary Disk: Where my personal files are stored

I have a dual booted computer ( Ubuntu and windows ). Again in Windows i have 2 users.
 I have certain files that i have made accessible to only one of the users by setting appropriate permissions through the "security" tab in "properties" . These files are on the secondary hard disk.

Now when when i boot to Ubuntu, i observed that all the files on the secondary hard disk was accessible  regardless of the permission set in Windows.
Why does this happen?  Why does Ubuntu just not block me from accessing them? Is the windows permission system different from that of Linux?

**P.S:** Since this question involves both Ubuntu and windows, i was in a dilemma where to post it. I hope the moderator will understand this confusion and  will not close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secondary disk is handled by both OS like an external drive, if these OS have the drivers to mount the filesystem (ie NTFS, exFAT) thus the files will be available. Ownership is only honored from the internal logic of each OS, without this there is no way to propagate the restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

*Is the windows permission system different from that of Linux?*
ANS: Yes. Each OS implements access to files following its own rules.

For example, the rights which can be assigned to a file in Linux are
Read, Write, and Execute. In contrast, Windows permissions are:

- Full control
- Modify
- Read
- Read and execute
- Write
- Special permissions

*Why does this happen?*
ANS: When this user mounted the Windows driver (and, presumably, its NTFS or FAT32 partition), access was not restricted.

*Why does Ubuntu just not block me from accessing them?*
ANS: Ubuntu (and Linux in general) have not been told to block their access.

You may notice the access rights of Windows allow greater atomicity, a more detailed set of privileges than does Linux.  Packages do exist which provide more specific levels of access for Linux, if needed.